# Is there an off the shelf IPython notebook widget for browsing images?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am looking for an image slideshow widget for IPython notebook. Something where I would just specific a list of image files it will load them, letting the notebook viewer go forward and backwards in the list like a slideshow.

Is there such a widget available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any dedicated widget, but this should be quite easy to implement with the tools provided by IPython directly. For example:

```
import os
from IPython.display import Image, display
from IPython.html.widgets import interact
path = '/home/yves/to/some/images'
imgs = list(filter(lambda fn:fn.lower().endswith('.jpg'), os.listdir(path)))
def loadimg(k):
    display(Image(open(os.path.join(path,imgs[k]),'rb').read()))
interact(loadimg ,k=(0,len(imgs)-1))
```